# AngularJs - Application with multiples modules

Tags: angularjs

I am a little bit stuck. I try to write my angular app following this recommendation : https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1/i18n

But i have this commun error : angular_v1.7.5.min.js:127 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.5/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=initController

There is my code :

```
    //app.js
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app', [
            'orion.user'
        ])
        .controller('initController', ["$scope", 'orion.user', initController]);

    function initController($scope, user) {
        var vm = $scope;
        console.log(user)
    }})(window.angular);

// user.module.js
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('orion.user', [
            'ngAnimate',
            'ngSanitize',
            'ngRoute'
        ]);

})(window.angular);

//index.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr" ng-app="app" ng-controller="initController">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#fff">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=3600" />
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public">

    <title>Test</title>  
</head>

<body>

    <script src="src/core/angular_v1.7.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/core/angular-sanitize_v1.7.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/core/angular-animate_v1.7.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/core/angular-route_v1.7.5.min.js"></script>

    <script src="src/user/user.module.js"></script> 
    <script src="src/user/user.factory.js"></script>
    <script src="src/user/user.controler.js"></script>

    <script src="src/core/app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

App.js is my main app named "app". I trie to initiate it calling user module. 
Can someone explain to me what i am doing wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you show where you use the controller?

Comment: Just add it on my first message

Answer (score 0):

You are not registering you controller properly.

try:

```
   /app.js
(function(angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular
    .module('app', [
        'orion.user'
    ])
    .controller('initController', ["$scope", 'orion.user', initController]);

    function initController($scope, user) {
        var vm = $scope;
        console.log(user)
    }})(window.angular);
```